# Cannot close header that suggest to join the community

Tags: bug, user-interface

Not working for the meta site either.

I've tried some other sites (not all) but this is the only one that give me this error

[image: Header that cannot be closed]

Comment: what happens if you click Join?

Comment: It does redirect me to sign-up page. The cool thing is that today the button says "Sign up" instead of "Join", so something has been changed, but the bug remains!

Comment: Interesting. I can't replicate it here, but SE staff will see this bug and work it out, I'm sure.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Chrome (Version 69.0.3497.100) but i also tested with Edge (40.15063.674.0)